# Maven Relase Plugin - Correct URLS for each git protocol

Tags: git, maven, gitlab, maven-release-plugin

Our ancient build uses Maven Relase Plugin to automatically increment the pom.xml version number and push this change back to git hosted at our gitlab instance. This build stopped working.

After some trial and error, we discovered that the URLs informed at scm/connection and scm/developerConnection elements were incorret within the pom.xml.

From the documentation of GIT (https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols) and Maven Relase Plugin (https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/usage.html), we inferred incorret URLs.

We expected (as the plugin documentation mentions that :// separates protocol from address):

- GIT using HTTP: `scm:git:http://github.com:8080/sample/sample-project.git`
- GIT using HTTPS: `scm:git:https://github.com:8080/sample/sample-project.git`
- GIT using SSH: `scm:git:ssh://[user@]server:22/sample/sample-project.git`
- GIT using native protol: `scm:git:git://github.com:port/sample/sample-project.git`

However, these URLs did not work.
After a while, we figured out that `scm:git:git@github.com:sample-project.git` worked...
But... Why? It does not seem to follow the documentation...

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#_git_urls. They are valid urls in git. Maybe the plugin only recognizes the scp-like syntax url.

Comment: How does your remote on cli look like? `git remote -v`?

Comment: @ElpieKay According to the documentation mentioned in your comment, our build worked using the "alternative scp-like syntax". At least now it makes some sense. Thank you for pointing this out! And the documentation explains that the other URLs should have worked, too. Since we are using a quite ancient version o gitlab, it might be possible that those protocols are not working as expected anymore...

Comment: @khmarbaise: `https://host/group/repository.git` . However, `scm:git:https://host/group/repository.git` did not work for the Maven Release Plugin...